# TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes) when importing sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import pandas
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as pltimg

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtree = dtree.fit(X, y)
y_pred = dtree.predict(X)
y_pred
```

The error ::

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-745bbfa9769b> in <module>
      1 import pandas
----> 2 from sklearn import tree
      3 import pydotplus
      4 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     12 from scipy import sparse
     13 from .externals import six
---> 14 from .utils.fixes import signature
     15 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     16 from . import __version__

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     12 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     13 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
---> 14 from . import _joblib
     15 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     16 from .fixes import _Sequence as Sequence

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_joblib.py in <module>
     20         from joblib import parallel_backend, register_parallel_backend
     21 else:
---> 22     from ..externals import joblib
     23     from ..externals.joblib import logger
     24     from ..externals.joblib import dump, load

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py in <module>
    117 from .numpy_pickle import load
    118 from .compressor import register_compressor
--> 119 from .parallel import Parallel
    120 from .parallel import delayed
    121 from .parallel import cpu_count

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <module>
     26 from .my_exceptions import TransportableException
     27 from .disk import memstr_to_bytes
---> 28 from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
     29                                  ThreadingBackend, SequentialBackend,
     30                                  LokyBackend)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in <module>
     20     from .pool import MemmappingPool
     21     from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
---> 22     from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
     23 
     24     # Compat between concurrent.futures and multiprocessing TimeoutError

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/executor.py in <module>
     12 from .disk import delete_folder
     13 from ._memmapping_reducer import get_memmapping_reducers
---> 14 from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
     15 
     16 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/__init__.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from .backend.context import cpu_count
---> 12 from .backend.reduction import set_loky_pickler
     13 from .reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
     14 from .cloudpickle_wrapper import wrap_non_picklable_objects

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py in <module>
    123 # global variable to change the pickler behavior
    124 try:
--> 125     from sklearn.externals.joblib.externals import cloudpickle  # noqa: F401
    126     DEFAULT_ENV = "cloudpickle"
    127 except ImportError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from .cloudpickle import *
      4 
      5 __version__ = '0.6.1'

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py in <module>
    165 
    166 
--> 167 _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
    168 
    169 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py in _make_cell_set_template_code()
    146         )
    147     else:
--> 148         return types.CodeType(
    149             co.co_argcount,
    150             co.co_kwonlyargcount,

TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

So I keep getting this type error and have no clue what to do pretty sure that sklearn is installed. Both X and y are previously defined after creating the training set to be used. I've tried reinstalling scikit-learn, downgrading python and installing through the terminal but none of that helped. Just cant figure out what the issue is here and will really appreciate some help on this

Comment: Where did you define `X` and `y`?

Comment: `features = ["loan_amnt","funded_amnt","int_rate","grade","annual_inc"]
X = trainingData[features]
y = trainingData["default_risk"] `

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting questions about errors in Python code it's more useful if you post the *full traceback* (everything from "Traceback (most recent call last)" leading up to the error, because that will help pinpoint exactly where in your code it's coming from.

Comment: thanks, @Iguananaut ! let me do that

Comment: See, this is important.  It looks like the problem has nothing to do with your code; it's happening while importing sklearn itself.

Comment: any ideas why? scikit-learn is installed already so im pretty lost here. sorry im a complete beginner

Comment: This issue is also being discussed at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17760

Comment: How did you create your conda environment?  Is there a way you can set up a fresh environment from scratch that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce the problem in a conda environment by running `conda install python==3.8 scikit-learn` but then manually downgrading `joblib` by running `pip install joblib<0.14` since `joblib<0.14` is incompatible with Python 3.8.

I'm not exactly sure how you got into the this situation, but it should fix it to first uninstall any `joblib` package that might have been mis-installed:

```
$ pip uninstall joblib
```

Then force reinstall/upgrade it with conda:

```
$ conda update --force-reinstall joblib
```

Confirm the correct version was installed:

```
$ python -c 'import joblib; print(joblib.__version__)'
0.17.0
```

If all else fails, try creating a fresh Anaconda install.  Make sure to install packages with `conda install` and not `pip`.

Comment: thank you so much you've been super helpful! but im still having no luck here. i've tried everything from creating a virtual environment to uninstalling and reinstalling joblib like you showed above. i honestly have no idea why this is happnening

Comment: What happens if you run `python -c 'import sys, joblib; print(sys.version); print(sys.path); print(joblib.__version__)'` ?

Comment: ```(base) salemnk@Salems-MacBook-Pro ~ % python -c 'import sys, joblib; print(sys.version); print(sys.path); print(joblib.__version__)'
3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ]
['', '/Users/salemnk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/salemnk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8', '/Users/salemnk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/salemnk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/Users/salemnk/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa']
0.17.0``` @Iguananaut

Comment: sorry for the long wait! this is what I get back please

Comment: I meant to ask. What does `print(sklearn); print(sklearn. __version__)` show? It looks like in your traceback it's actually using a vendored copy of joblib which the sklearn devs say isn't used in newer versions

Comment: hey @Iguananaut thank you so much for the help on this! finally got it to work after reinstalling anaconda, making sure my dependencies for sklearn were all matching versions and removing this line of code - ``` from sklearn import tree ```   after that i installed homebrew using Rosetta 2 and then brew installed graphviz

Answer (score 1):

In my case, joblib in scikit needs to be reinstalled.

> pip uninstall joblib

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I pip installed `sklearn` instead of `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did

```
pip uninstall sklearn --yes
```

followed by

```
pip install sklearn
```